# Angular tour of heroes ngModule error

Tags: javascript, angular

[image][image]I'm following the steps of the Tour of heroes for the new Angular but I'm getting stuck in one part. In the step of including ngModule for the two way data binding for the hero.name I get an error. After watching video's it said its because I need to import the ngmodule when I reload my page it doesn't display anything. Below is the error it gives me. That code belongs in my index.html . Everything until the steps of ngModule was working till now. The error is at the end .error(err); part.

```
System.import('main.js').catch(function(err){ console.error(err);});
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: It's hard to know exactly what you are asking without more context but I would assume in your main module you will need to import the forms module.

Comment: can you attach the console error

Comment: I did include the forms module but its still not working.

Comment: I included just now a screen shot of the error being thrown

Comment: @Richard it says there is an error in main.js file. You can try to find the error in main.js(or TS) or you can add the contents of the main.js file here so we can help you

Comment: I attached my main.js screen shot @jackjop .